# Overload a form in symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, overloading

I would like to overload a form of the bundle FOSComment. I would like to know i have to create a new bundle Comment or if i can do it from my working/main bundle ?

Sorry for my english.

Thank you,
David

```
namespace FOS\CommentBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    private $commentClass;

    public function __construct($commentClass)
    {
        $this->commentClass = $commentClass;
    }

    /**
     * Configures a Comment form.
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('body', 'textarea')
                ->add('lien', 'text', array('required'      => false,
                                            'empty_data'    => null));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->commentClass,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "fos_comment_comment";
    }
}
```

For the moment i put my field lien directly in the vendor file which i know is not the good way.

Comment: you want to override form controller or twig template from that bundle ?

Comment: Hi Straw, i put the form i need in the topic. Need to override the formtype.

Answer (score 0):

i think all you need to do is override the service definition of the form you want to overload:

e.g. (if you have a services.yml)

```
fos_comment.form_type.comment.default
    class: Project/MyBundle/Form/CustomFormType
    arguments:[%fos_comment.model.comment.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: fos_comment_comment }
```

Comment: Thanks Derick. Yes i have a service.yml, i used to do some services but not very good at. :)
I put the form i need to overload in my topic. Do you have a link where i can find examples on how to whrite the service ?